# How can I absolutely position a "resize handle" above another element with position sticky?

Tags: css, positioning

I am trying to add a "resize handle" (green) to div-based table. The cell header (red) needs to be "sticky" because the table has to scroll and the header should be always visible. I would like the "resize handle" (green) to be above the next header.

As you can see on the Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/andrerpena/pen/zYzqmQm), if the table header is "sticky", the absolutely positioned handle (green) cannot overflow over the next header (z-index doesnt matter because of the stack context, I think). I would like the resize handle to be above the cell headers.

[image]

https://codepen.io/andrerpena/pen/zYzqmQm

Any idea?

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.resize-handle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  right: -50px;
  background-color: green;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: increase the z-index of the first sticky header

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm so dumb. Thanks, that works. If you want to write that as an aswer I'm happy to accept. Thanks a again